# passing variables inside find element method in Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android-testing

how to pass variables inside find element method in Selenium or Appium using Java?

Is it possible to pass the 'GROUP' (value = users) in the below example as a parameter to the method and how to do it? I have a list like users, field, etc and I want  pass users or field as a parameter and find the element passed on what I'm passing.
eg:

```
public static boolean select(group){
dr.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(group)").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sendkeys()` to pass the value to the field.